# Rotate image inside svg file in a loop inside another object

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to make a bowling ball rotate in a loop inside another image but the center of gravity is outside the center of the other image and I can't figure it out how to do it.

The svg file is:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="icono-zaragoza" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="350px" height="270.439px" viewBox="0 0 350 270.439" enable-background="new 0 0 350 270.439" xml:space="preserve">
    <image overflow="visible" width="350" height="268" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/NI4toqy.png"  transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -14.313 -2.3545)">
    </image>
    <image id="zaragozaBolod" class="rotating" overflow="visible" width="136" height="136" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/m5hqaZ1.png"  transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 112.9995 67.625)">
    </image>
</svg>
```

And the css I'm using:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
  from{
       -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to{
       -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.rotating {
    -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}
```

This is an example of what is happening: http://jsfiddle.net/FswgL/

Comment: Have you tried `transform-origin`? For instance `.rotating { -webkit-transform-origin: 68px 68px; }`

Comment: Yeah thanks, adding to .rotating transform-origin fixes one of the problems. Now I have the sphere rotating right, but I can't move it to the center of the other circle. Removing the .rotating class the ball is where it should be but after aplying the class, it rotates outside.

Comment: I also managed to remove all the css code just adding in the second image: `<animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 68 68" to="360 68 68" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>` But the ball still plays outside the other circle -.-